# Postgres Connection Reset (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm using a fresh install of Postgres 9.6 on Windows 10 and got spurious connection errors from simple JDBC code (Connection Reset). Note that I've weird errors from pgadmin as well. Note that code is working fine when connection to a Linux Postgres server.

Is there any way to access the server logs to see what is wrong with my install?

JDBC stacktrace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:275)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:431)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:247)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:282)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:418)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)
    ... 44 more
```

[edit] Some more details after the comments:

In Java code it happens at random when requesting a connection, when processing a statement, etc...

Local machine only: the server and the machine on the same Windows 10 box.

PGAdmin is behaving strangely (again at random) saying it cannot connect to the server, saying the server has stopped, etc...

Did a re-install using the BIGsql Windows installer (9.6.2-1a) and now the server looks ok. 
Sorry cannot remember the previous package installed.

Comment: You'll need to show the code and the error message, and probably relevant database parameters (`port`, `listen_addresses`, ...) as well.

Comment: Anything is throwing the exception ( Connection Reset )... the login, a simple SELECT, ...this is an error happening at random. Even PGADMIN is behaving strangely...

Comment: No, that is not enough. You should describe when the error happens. When you establish the connection? In the middle of work? Does it happen always or only occasionally? Also, your error descriptions are inadequate. If pgAdmin III has similar problems, describe them exactly - for example, pgAdmin cannot throw a stack trace like the one above. I know it is painful to type, copy and paste - but 1) it is the only way for anybody to guess what's going on, and 2) in 50% of the cases, when you sit down and describe a problem thoroughly, you'll find the solution in the process. Any firewalls?